# Spring Boot. Error import/find c3p0-0.9.5.2

Tags: spring, maven

guys.In spring boot project I use c3p0-0.9.5.2. 
Add dependencies

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I importing import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
IDEA says Cannot resolve symbol c3p0.
Command mvn clean install shows:

```
.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar; error in opening zip file
.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar; cannot read zip file
package com.mchange.v2.c3p0 does not exist
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Likely a corrupted download. Delete `.m2\repository\com\mchange\c3p0\0.9.5.2\c3p0` folder and `mvn install` or `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to delete dependencies from current project and require

Comment: I have already done this several times

Comment: With two dependencies above dosen't work. When I add c3p0-0.9.1.2 all work.